# Why is the Azure App Configuration feature flag not found?

Tags: azure-app-configuration, feature-flags

Azure Functions app, runtime v3.

The application has a `FunctionsStartup` class that first enables Azure App Configuration in its `ConfigureAppConfiguration` method:

```
builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options
        .Connect(appConfigurationConnectionString)
        .UseFeatureFlags();
});
```

And in its `Configure` method it enables feature management, and it adds the Azure App Configuration services (so we can refresh settings at runtime):

```
builder.Services
    .AddAzureAppConfiguration()
    .AddFeatureManagement()
    .AddFeatureFilter<ContextualTargetingFilter>();
```

On the Azure Portal there is a feature flag, which is enabled, called `CardExpirationNotice`. The code uses `IFeatureManagerSnapshot` to check if the feature is enabled:

```
feature = nameof(Features.CardExpirationNotice);
var isEnabled = await _featureManagerSnapshot.IsEnabledAsync(feature);
```

`isEnabled` is `false`, and this log message is output:

> The feature declaration for the feature 'CardExpirationNotice' was not found.

I tried configuring a flag locally in local.settings.json:

```
"FeatureManagement__CardExpirationNotice": true
```

Then `isEnabled` is `true`, so I can narrow the problem to Azure App Configuration, and exclude the feature management implementation.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, when you add a feature flag in Azure App Configuration, you can set a label. But if you do that, then you need to specify that label in your code as well:

```
builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options
        .Connect(appConfigurationConnectionString)
        .UseFeatureFlags(options => options.Label = "payments");
});
```